# Database within a Database in Databricks

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

Is it possible to have a folder or database with a database in Azure Databricks?  I know you can use the "create database if not exists xxx" to get a database, but I want to have folders within that database where I can put tables.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your question you want to have a database stored in specific location? Then you can use `CREATE DATABASE` with explicit `LOCATION` parameter (see [docs](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-create-database.html)), like this:

```sql
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS <name>
LOCATION 'path to folder';
```

And then all data for tables in this database will be stored under given location.

P.S. You can also specify path for table explicitly, when writing, using the option `path`:

```py
df.write.format("delta").option("path", "path_to_table")\
   .saveAsTable("database.table")
```

Comment: That doesn't appear to be working with databricks.  What do you need to put as "path to folder" to make it work?  Right now I have this:

CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS testing
LOCATION 'database/xxx/';

Comment: you need to use absolute path

Comment: Database and tables are the logical entries, pointing to the data somewhere on the disk (location is either default, or user-specified)